# Can a thread run two method simultaneously?

Tags: java, multithreading

so I have created the following thread:

```
public class test extends thread{
    public void run(){
        // Do stuff
    }
    public void onPause(){
        //Do stuff to prepare for pausing
    }
}
```

Now my question is suppose that this thread is currently executing the run() method and all of the sudden from a main thread I call onPause() then would that make it stop executing the run() and execute the onPause() method or would they both run simultaneously?

Comment: why do you think it wouldn't?

Comment: `this` thread would be executing `run()`.  The "main" thread would be executing `onPause()`.  Two threads, each executing a separate sequence of instructions.  One thread can't do two things at once, but two threads can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They would run concurrently because as you pointed out you're calling `onPause` from the main thread.

Comment: Oh shoot I been wreking my head over this and now you brought it up I see it now thannks. I was thinking that when I call onPause() the current thread running is call onPause() while executing run(). Now looking over it I realized this is a very dumb question

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually it's a mistake to confuse Thread objects with actual threads. A thread is allocated to a Thread object, so that calling start on the Thread executes the Thread's  (or its Runnable's) run method on that thread.

A Thread is just another object and (unless you do something to restrict access such as adding locking) there is nothing stopping multiple threads from executing its methods. So your Thread's run method can be called concurrently; if your run method calls a method on Thread, like isInterrupted, that's going to check the state of the Thread object as opposed to the state of the thread executing the method.
(Using Thread.currentThread() accesses the executing thread.)

One of the advantages of making a habit of not extending Thread and instead implementing Runnable or Callable is that there is a little less room for confusion, as you're not inheriting Thread methods.